# How do a serialize a member of a .net Object

Tags: c#, xml, serialization

I have a class that has a field with a type of System.Diagnostics.Process. I want to serialize my object, but that doesnt seem to be possible. Would it be possible to 
1. Serialize the member process by its property process.StartInfo.FileName
2 When I deserialize that I want to try to remake process using the FileName, using its constructor.

To give some example code

```
 public class Job{
     /*[something like SerializeMember("StartInfo.FileName")]*/
     /*[something like DeserializeMember(new Process(value))]*/
     System.Diagnostics.Process process;
     string name;
 }
```

If there is a better way to do this, feel free to add that.

Comment: Which serializer are you going to use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can achieve this by creating a property that you'd serialize, and then on set of property try to launch process.  Here is semi-pseudo-code for it...

```
 public class Job{
     [XmlIgnore]
     System.Diagnostics.Process process;

     public ProcessFileName
     {
         get {return process.StartInfo.FileName;}
         set { process = Process.Start(value); }
     }
 }
```

Comment: If the BinaryFormatter is used for serialization you should also apply the `NonSerialized` Attribute to the member

Answer (score 1):

Maybe adding a property would help.

```
public SomeSerializableClass SerializedProcess 
{
  get {
     ConvertProcessToSomeSerializableClass(process);
  }
  set {
      process = ConvertSomeSerialzableClassToProcess(value);
  }
}
```

Then on `process` add the attribute `[XmlIgnore]`

Comment: I was actually seconds ahead!  No worries though :)